# Autofilling MySql tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I've created a mySQL database. I was wondering if there was anyway to simply autofill the tables or to create insert statements that will remain in the code. I'm trying to avoid having to fill in the tables with tons of information. So my question is how do you autofill entity tables in mySQL with data, if it is even possible?

Comment: Various Fields All in all I have about 40 different attributes ranging from integers for ID numbers street numbers and the rest is mostly variable characters for like names, job titles and much more. I also have other data types  like double. but the primary ones are integers and variable character's. @strawberry

Comment: you should look at defaults https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

Comment: I would like to put in dummy data, but I do not want it all to be the same particular with integers and I don't want it to self increment. I understand you can make everything a unique index but I am not looking for defaults I'm more interested in Randomly generated data that will autofill my tables. @MarshallTigerus

Comment: you should use PHP, or another programming language, and make use of case statements and random number generators to fill in dummy data.  It would probably take 30m-1hr to write the code to do it, and even a novice should eb able too

Comment: Ya thanks @MarshallTigerus realized MySQL couldn't do what I wanted.